# Bind Ckeditor value to model text in AngularJS and Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, angularjs

I want to bind CKEditor text to `ng-model` text. My View:

```html
    <form name="postForm" method="POST" ng-submit="submit()" csrf-tokenized class="form-horizontal">
  

    <fieldset>
    <legend>Post to: </legend>
    <div class="control-group">
      <label class="control-label">Text input</label>
      <div class="controls">
        <div class="textarea-wrapper">
          <textarea id="ck_editor" name="text" ng-model="text" class="fullwidth"></textarea>
        </div>
        <p class="help-block">Supporting help text</p>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-actions">
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Post</button>
      <button class="btn">Cancel</button>
      <button class="btn" onclick="alert(ckglobal.getDate())">Cancel123</button>
    </div>
  </fieldset>
</form>
```

controller

```js
      function PostFormCtrl($scope, $element, $attrs, $transclude, $http, $rootScope) {
      $scope.form = $element.find("form");
      $scope.text = "";
    
      $scope.submit = function() {
          $http.post($scope.url, $scope.form.toJSON()).
          success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                  $rootScope.$broadcast("newpost");
                  $scope.form[0].reset();
              });
      };
    
      $scope.alert1 = function(msg) {
          var sval = $element.find("ckglobal");
          //$('.jquery_ckeditor').ckeditor(ckeditor);                                                                                                                      
          alert(sval);
      };
    }
    PostFormCtrl.$inject = ["$scope", "$element", "$attrs", "$transclude", "$http", "$rootScope"];
```

I want to set CKEditor value in `$scope.text` at the time of form submit.

Answer (score 76, accepted):

CKEditor does not update textarea while typing, so you need to take care of it.

**Here's a directive that will make ng-model binding work with CK:**

```js
angular.module('ck', []).directive('ckEditor', function() {
  return {
    require: '?ngModel',
    link: function(scope, elm, attr, ngModel) {
      var ck = CKEDITOR.replace(elm[0]);

      if (!ngModel) return;

      ck.on('pasteState', function() {
        scope.$apply(function() {
          ngModel.$setViewValue(ck.getData());
        });
      });

      ngModel.$render = function(value) {
        ck.setData(ngModel.$viewValue);
      };
    }
  };
});
```

In html, just use:

```html
<textarea ck-editor ng-model="value"></textarea>
```

---

The previous code will update ng-model on every change.

**If you only want to update binding on save, override "save" plugin, to not do anything but fire "save" event.**

```js
// modified ckeditor/plugins/save/plugin.js
CKEDITOR.plugins.registered['save'] = {
  init: function(editor) {
    var command = editor.addCommand('save', {
      modes: {wysiwyg: 1, source: 1},
      readOnly: 1,
      exec: function(editor) {
        editor.fire('save');
      }
    });

    editor.ui.addButton('Save', {
      label : editor.lang.save,
      command : 'save'
    });
  }
};
```

And then, use this event inside the directive:

```js
angular.module('ck', []).directive('ckEditor', function() {
  return {
    require: '?ngModel',
    link: function(scope, elm, attr, ngModel) {
      var ck = CKEDITOR.replace(elm[0]);

      if (!ngModel) return;

      ck.on('save', function() {
        scope.$apply(function() {
          ngModel.$setViewValue(ck.getData());
        });
      });
    }
  };
});
```

Comment: This is great.  And much better than the TinyMCE example in the Angular-UI project.

Comment: Thanks, works much better than my directive.
For those, who write in CoffeeScript: https://gist.github.com/paprikka/5000011

Comment: There is a memory leak with this directive if you navigate using location.path. Add this to correct it :

    elm.bind('$destroy', function() {
     ck.destroy();
    });

Also, a fix was suggested here for a binding problem : 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15483579/angularjs-ckeditor-directive-sometimes-fails-to-load-data-from-a-service

Comment: For newbies (like me) remember `angular.module('ck', [])` will create a new module, if you have an existing one use `angular.module('ck')` as the `[]` overwrites the old module.

This simple mistake cost me about 30 minutes since I'm not very good at JS or Angular!

Comment: For those who are using image insert, tables, pastefromword, etc: I needed to add the same functionality as on `'pasteState'`, but in stead on `'paste'` to get it to update immediately after one of these are inserted into the body.
Thanks for this [@Vojta](http://stackoverflow.com/users/531342/vojta)!

Comment: And on `'drop'` as well for drag and drop of images with `scope.$apply(function(){$timeout(function(){ngModel.$setViewValue(ck.getData());})});`. $timeout is to wait until the change to be applied.

Comment: As of ckeditor 4.2, there's the 'change' event which should be used instead of 'pasteState'.

Comment: @DanCaragea thanks it was very helpful for me because I use ckeditor with bbcode plugin and ckeditor does not detect smiley insert in the case were smiley was at the end of my content

Comment: There is also slight problem with form controller being dirty because the state ngModel.$setViewValue fires when control is bound.  You can add a check to see if the values are the same before setting the view value to keep this from happening
  ck.on('pasteState', function () {
                var data = ck.getData();
                if (data !== ngModel.$viewValue) {
                    $scope.$apply(function () {
                        ngModel.$setViewValue(ck.getData());
                    });
                }
            });

Comment: @vojta Update your answer as per DanCaragea comment

Answer (score 7):

If you simply want to retrieve text in the editor textarea in angular, call `CKEDITOR.instances.editor1.getData();` to get the value directly in an angularjs function. See below.

In your html

In the test.controller.js

```
(function () {
    'use strict';

    angular
        .module('app')
            .controller('test', test);

    test.$inject = []; 

    function test() {

        //this is to replace $scope
        var vm = this;

        //function definition
        function postJob()
        {          
            vm.Description = CKEDITOR.instances.editor1.getData();
            alert(vm.Description);
        }
    } 
})();
```

Comment: This is so much simpler than the dozen other solutions I've seen on the web!!!  (Most of the other solutions don't even work, or have bugs.)  This simple solution was literally ONE LINE of code that I added!!!  It also works with the "Source" mode in CKEditor - which other solutions didn't.  And it worked with my existing CKEditor configuration code.

Comment: I just spent 4 hours trying to get all the directives to work with existing html data in the editor.....nothing worked correctly. THIS answer worked in 5 minutes...bliss :)  Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

the Vojta answer work partly

in this post I found a solution

https://stackoverflow.com/a/18236359/1058096

the final code:

```
.directive('ckEditor', function() {
                return {
                    require : '?ngModel',
                    link : function($scope, elm, attr, ngModel) {

                        var ck = CKEDITOR.replace(elm[0]);

                        ck.on('instanceReady', function() {
                            ck.setData(ngModel.$viewValue);
                        });

                        ck.on('pasteState', function() {
                            $scope.$apply(function() {
                                ngModel.$setViewValue(ck.getData());
                            });
                        });

                        ngModel.$render = function(value) {
                            ck.setData(ngModel.$modelValue);
                        };
                    }
                };
            })
```

edit: removed unused brackets

Comment: Is there any utility in putting the entire function in brackets?

Comment: If i have done changes in source data without watching view data it is not picking the changes how can i manage for those cases?

Comment: One More Que: if have added **change** event the it will left the last string whichever i updated

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to Vojta for the excellent directive.  Sometimes it doesn't load.  Here is a modified version to fix that issue.

```
angular.module('ck', []).directive('ckEditor', function() {
  var calledEarly, loaded;
  loaded = false;
  calledEarly = false;

  return {
    require: '?ngModel',
    compile: function(element, attributes, transclude) {
      var loadIt, local;

      local = this;
      loadIt = function() {
        return calledEarly = true;
      };

      element.ready(function() {
        return loadIt();
      });

      return {
        post: function($scope, element, attributes, controller) {
          if (calledEarly) {
            return local.link($scope, element, attributes, controller);
          }
          loadIt = (function($scope, element, attributes, controller) {
            return function() {
              local.link($scope, element, attributes, controller);
            };
          })($scope, element, attributes, controller);
        }
      };
    },

    link: function($scope, elm, attr, ngModel) {
      var ck;
      if (!ngModel) {
        return;
      }

      if (calledEarly && !loaded) {
        return loaded = true;
      }
      loaded = false;

      ck = CKEDITOR.replace(elm[0]);
      ck.on('pasteState', function() {
        $scope.$apply(function() {
          ngModel.$setViewValue(ck.getData());
        });
      });

      ngModel.$render = function(value) {
        ck.setData(ngModel.$viewValue);
      };
    }
  };
});
```

or if you need it in coffeescript

```
angular.module('ck', []).directive('ckEditor', ->
  loaded = false
  calledEarly = false
  {
    require: '?ngModel',
    compile: (element, attributes, transclude) ->
      local = @
      loadIt = ->
        calledEarly = true

      element.ready ->
        loadIt()
      post: ($scope, element, attributes, controller) ->
        return local.link $scope, element, attributes, controller if calledEarly

        loadIt = (($scope, element, attributes, controller) ->
          return ->
            local.link $scope, element, attributes, controller
        )($scope, element, attributes, controller)
    link: ($scope, elm, attr, ngModel) ->
      return unless ngModel

      if (calledEarly and not loaded)
        return loaded = true
      loaded = false

      ck = CKEDITOR.replace(elm[0])

      ck.on('pasteState', ->
        $scope.$apply( ->
          ngModel.$setViewValue(ck.getData())
        )
      )

      ngModel.$render = (value) ->
        ck.setData(ngModel.$viewValue)
  }
)
```

Comment: I've tried this code. ckEditor still doesn't load every time. How were the changes supposed to prevent the problem?

Comment: You need to destroy prev instances

Comment: jimmy, i am having the same issues of the data does not load everytime. How and where would i destroy prev instances?

Answer (score 1):

And just for the record if you want to use multiple editors in one page this can come in handy:

```
mainApp.directive('ckEditor', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'A', // only activate on element attribute
        scope: false,
        require: 'ngModel',
        controller: function($scope, $element, $attrs) {}, //open for now
        link: function($scope, element, attr, ngModel, ngModelCtrl) {
            if(!ngModel) return; // do nothing if no ng-model you might want to remove this
            element.bind('click', function(){
                for(var name in CKEDITOR.instances)
                    CKEDITOR.instances[name].destroy();
                var ck = CKEDITOR.replace(element[0]);
                ck.on('instanceReady', function() {
                    ck.setData(ngModel.$viewValue);
                });
                ck.on('pasteState', function() {
                    $scope.$apply(function() {
                        ngModel.$setViewValue(ck.getData());
                    });
                });
                ngModel.$render = function(value) {
                    ck.setData(ngModel.$viewValue);
                };
            });
        }
    }
});
```

This will destroy all previous instances of ckeditor and create a new one.

Answer (score 0):

There's now a 'change' event that can be used for this.

Here's a directive I've just created that has a couple of different toolbar config options, I'm using the jQuery adapter to initialize ckeditor. For more info check out [this blog post](http://jasonwatmore.com/post/2016/05/26/Angular-CKEditor-Directive-with-ngModel-Binding.aspx).

```
(function () {
    'use strict';

    angular
        .module('app')
        .directive('wysiwyg', Directive);

    function Directive($rootScope) {
        return {
            require: 'ngModel',
            link: function (scope, element, attr, ngModel) {
                var editorOptions;
                if (attr.wysiwyg === 'minimal') {
                    // minimal editor
                    editorOptions = {
                        height: 100,
                        toolbar: [
                            { name: 'basic', items: ['Bold', 'Italic', 'Underline'] },
                            { name: 'links', items: ['Link', 'Unlink'] },
                            { name: 'tools', items: ['Maximize'] },
                            { name: 'document', items: ['Source'] },
                        ],
                        removePlugins: 'elementspath',
                        resize_enabled: false
                    };
                } else {
                    // regular editor
                    editorOptions = {
                        filebrowserImageUploadUrl: $rootScope.globals.apiUrl + '/files/uploadCk',
                        removeButtons: 'About,Form,Checkbox,Radio,TextField,Textarea,Select,Button,ImageButton,HiddenField,Save,CreateDiv,Language,BidiLtr,BidiRtl,Flash,Iframe,addFile,Styles',
                        extraPlugins: 'simpleuploads,imagesfromword'
                    };
                }

                // enable ckeditor
                var ckeditor = element.ckeditor(editorOptions);

                // update ngModel on change
                ckeditor.editor.on('change', function () {
                    ngModel.$setViewValue(this.getData());
                });
            }
        };
    }
})();
```

Here's a couple of examples of how to use the directive in HTML

```
<textarea ng-model="vm.article.Body" wysiwyg></textarea>
<textarea ng-model="vm.article.Body" wysiwyg="minimal"></textarea>
```

And here are the CKEditor scripts I'm including from a CDN plus a couple of extra plugins that I downloaded to enable pasting images from word.

```
<script src="//cdn.ckeditor.com/4.5.7/full/ckeditor.js"></script>
<script src="//cdn.ckeditor.com/4.5.7/full/adapters/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    // load extra ckeditor plugins
    CKEDITOR.plugins.addExternal('simpleuploads', '/js/ckeditor/plugins/simpleuploads/plugin.js');
    CKEDITOR.plugins.addExternal('imagesfromword', '/js/ckeditor/plugins/imagesfromword/plugin.js');
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

ES6 example with CKEditor v5.

Register directive using:

```
   angular.module('ckeditor', []).directive('ckEditor', CkEditorDirective.create)
```

Directive:

```
import CkEditor from "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-build-classic";
export default class CkEditorDirective {

   constructor() {
     this.restrict = 'A';
     this.require = 'ngModel';
   }

  static create() {
    return new CkEditorDirective();
  }

  link(scope, elem, attr, ngModel) {
    CkEditor.create(elem[0]).then((editor) => {
      editor.document.on('changesDone', () => {
        scope.$apply(() => {
          ngModel.$setViewValue(editor.getData());
        });
      });

      ngModel.$render = () => {
        editor.setData(ngModel.$modelValue);
      };

      scope.$on('$destroy', () => {
        editor.destroy();
      });
    })
  }
}
```