# Updating textarea value with CKEditor content in Angular JS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ckeditor, angularjs-directive, wysiwyg

I am using latest CKEditor (Standard Version) and based on this
[question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11997246/bind-ckeditor-value-to-model-text-in-angularjs-and-rails) , I have implemented an angular directive like this,

```
var cmsPlus = angular.module('cmsPlus', []);

cmsPlus.directive('ckEditor', function() {
  return {
    require: '?ngModel',
    link: function(scope, elm, attr, ngModel) {
      var ck = CKEDITOR.replace(elm[0]);

      if (!ngModel) return;

      ck.on('pasteState', function() {
        scope.$apply(function() {
          ngModel.$setViewValue(ck.getData());
        });
      });

      ngModel.$render = function(value) {
        ck.setData(ngModel.$viewValue);
      };
    }
  };
});
```

It's working fine when I am typing something in CKEditor GUI mode, here I am getting the typed content to textarea's ng-model.

But when I am switching to code-editor, it's not getting the updated content even after switch back to GUI. It's required to type something again in graphical mode.

What is wrong with my directive? Or can I extend this directive with some other CKEditor events?

I want add some more events for form submit or something else.

***[Demo here.](http://jsfiddle.net/fdD63/1/)***

Comment: Didn't someone suggest binding directly to the DOM element that gets created when cke goes into source mode? Did that not work? I thought it was pretty clever.

Comment: How are you using the directive? If you could provide a real example using jsFiddle or plnkr it would be easier to help!

Comment: @JonasHartmann Check my link in question, and we can see instant update when I am entering in GUI and it's not updating when typing with source view.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Your directive is working well.

There is a plugin called **sourcearea** that controls the CKEditor behavior while on *source mode*. I couldn't see any event being fire inside the code of that plugin for handling input. There are though two events that we can use to catch when the CKEditor goes back to 
*GUI mode*. The events are **ariaWidget** and **dataReady**.

I've updated your example to use the **dataReady** event, so it updates the textarea when switching back. I also changed the **pasteState** event to **change**, as [Dan Caragea said](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11997246/bind-ckeditor-value-to-model-text-in-angularjs-and-rails#comment27180866_12021632) it was introduced in version 4.2.
 [Updated fiddle can be found here](http://jsfiddle.net/fdD63/3/)

One almost-there-solution I found is to listen to the **key** event and update the model. It is almost there, because it seems the event is only fired for the old key pressed. So the last key is always missing.

```
var cmsPlus = angular.module('cmsPlus', []);

cmsPlus.directive('ckEditor', function() {
  return {
    require: '?ngModel',
    link: function(scope, elm, attr, ngModel) {
      var ck = CKEDITOR.replace(elm[0]);

      if (!ngModel) return;

      ck.on('instanceReady', function() {
        ck.setData(ngModel.$viewValue);
      });

      function updateModel() {
          scope.$apply(function() {
              ngModel.$setViewValue(ck.getData());
          });
      }

      ck.on('change', updateModel);
      ck.on('key', updateModel);
      ck.on('dataReady', updateModel);

      ngModel.$render = function(value) {
        ck.setData(ngModel.$viewValue);
      };
    }
  };
});
```

Anyway, maybe you can figure out from this how to fix the last key problem. It is almost there!

EDIT: updated fiddle link to correct version

Comment: @Jonas - Can you tell me why you chose to use $viewValue in the ck.setdata and not $modelValue. I am starting to see some ckEditor directives that use one and others that use the other.

Comment: @Alan - First, I just modified the code from the OP. But I think it makes more sense to use the $viewValue, because when we call ck.setdata, we want to present the data to the user. The $viewValue is the data ready to be displayed.

Comment: Something I would suggest is to add string trim into both sides, so that you can test for form modifications reliably. See jsfiddle.net/fdD63/12. CKEditor always adds a newline, so incoming HTML from a database might not match even though the only difference is the newline that ckeditor adds.

Comment: how can i upload multiple images like in http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/616308/Image-upload-with-CKEditor

Comment: @rajeshpanwar: Please transform your comment into a question.

Comment: i have already asked that question but didnot get any reply.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21986869/ckeditor-angularjs-directive-how-to-upload-multiple-images Please help me how to resolve it?

Comment: FYI: I was running into the odd `$digest` issue, so I had to add `$timeout` around the `scope.$apply` in `updateModel`

Answer (score 9):

I know this question has already been answered, but I thought I'd chime in with what I had to do to integrate CKEditor 4.4.4 with angularjs 1.2.  Here is my code in coffeescript:

```
'use strict'

angular.module 'core', []

.directive 'ckeditor', ->
    require: '?ngModel'
    link: (scope, element, attrs, ngModel) ->
        config =
            # CKEditor config goes here

        editor = CKEDITOR.replace element[0], config

        return unless ngModel

        editor.on 'instanceReady', ->
            editor.setData ngModel.$viewValue

        updateModel = ->
            scope.$apply ->
                ngModel.$setViewValue editor.getData()

        editor.on 'change', updateModel
        editor.on 'dataReady', updateModel
        editor.on 'key', updateModel
        editor.on 'paste', updateModel
        editor.on 'selectionChange', updateModel

        ngModel.$render = ->
            editor.setData ngModel.$viewValue
```

For the coffeescript illiterate, here is the compiled javascript:

```
'use strict';
angular.module('core', []).directive('ckeditor', function() {
    return {
      require: '?ngModel',
      link: function(scope, element, attrs, ngModel) {
        var config, editor, updateModel;
        config = {
            // CKEditor config goes here
        }
        editor = CKEDITOR.replace(element[0], config);
        if (!ngModel) {
          return;
        }
        editor.on('instanceReady', function() {
          return editor.setData(ngModel.$viewValue);
        });
        updateModel = function() {
          return scope.$apply(function() {
            return ngModel.$setViewValue(editor.getData());
          });
        }};
        editor.on('change', updateModel);
        editor.on('dataReady', updateModel);
        editor.on('key', updateModel);
        editor.on('paste', updateModel);
        editor.on('selectionChange', updateModel);
        return ngModel.$render = function() {
          return editor.setData(ngModel.$viewValue);
        };
      }
    };
  }
);
```

Then in the HTML:

```
<textarea ckeditor data-ng-model="myModel"></textarea>
```

Now, for an explanation.

I added paste and selection change handlers for completeness, but it turns out the selection change handler was necessary.  I discovered that if I selected all and hit delete, then—without taking focus off the editor—submitted the form, the changes where not reflected in the model on submit.  The selection change handler solves that problem.

Integrating CKEditor with angularjs is mission critical for my project, so if I find anymore “Gotchas”, I will update this answer.

Comment: Selection change handler saved me! Thanks.

Comment: Me too!..thanks a lot :) If you use nanospell with this, adding it after the textarea replace works. Like this:      
    nanospell.ckeditor(element[0].id, { dictionary: "en", server: "asp.net" });

Answer (score 0):

I am hoping the issue is similar to mine.
The CK Editor has its own elements that it injects into the DOM and Angular is already rendered so you will need to set up a listener for when it transitions to the code editor. If you are not listening for the change then Angular cannot bind properly because it is unaware of the changes in the DOM. I ran into something similar with tinymce and the modal that pops up.

[Here is another resource that is related to my issue](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15483580/1050401)

Comment: I don't think that's the issue here because OP is using native ckeditor events and API and not DOM binding.

Comment: If you inspect element on the text area when you click on source code, the directive is gone. devo is not DOM binding but ckedit is obliterating his directive when the source code button is clicked so AngularJS has no idea what to bind to because the directive has been destroyed. The DOM got updated without Angular's knolwedge. Try making the directive a class and allow for transclusion. *restrict: 'C', replace: true, transclude: true,*

Comment: EDIT: grr... Apparently ckEdit destroys your classes as well :/ I hope I am on the right track but trying something else

Answer (score 0):

For me the answer by @Mjonir74 worked but as soon as i had multiple editor instances on a page and had to also take into consideration the edit mode not just create mode, things started to not work properly when you'd come back to the page containing the editor. Basically in edit mode, first time you'd visit the page, all was fine, text was in the editor as it should. but any successive visits to same page left the editor empty, no text.

Here's the way it worked for me:

```
    app.directive('appWysiwygBlock', function() {
    return {
        require: 'ngModel',
        restrict: 'E',
        templateUrl: 'modules/app/templates/directives/wysiwyg-block.html',
        scope: {
            error: '=',
            config: '='
        },
        link: function(scope, element, attrs, ngModel) {

            if (typeof CKEDITOR == 'undefined' || !ngModel) {
                return;
            }

            scope.required = attrs.required || false;
            scope.cols = attrs.cols || 6;

            scope.label = attrs.label || attrs.name;
            scope.name = attrs.name || scope.label;
            if (scope.name) {
                scope.name = scope.name.toLowerCase().replace(/[^a-z0-9]/gi, '_');
            }

            var defaultConfig, config, editor, updateModel;

            config = scope.config || {};
            defaultConfig = {
                customConfig: '/modules/app/ckeditor-config.js'
            };

            config = element.extend({}, defaultConfig, config);
            editor = CKEDITOR.replace(element.find('textarea:first')[0], config);

            updateModel = function() {
                return scope.$apply(function() {
                    return ngModel.$setViewValue(editor.getData());
                });
            };

            editor.on('instanceReady', function() {
                editor.on('change', updateModel);
                editor.on('dataReady', updateModel);
                editor.on('key', updateModel);
                editor.on('paste', updateModel);
                editor.on('selectionChange', updateModel);
                return editor.setData(ngModel.$viewValue);
            });

            return ngModel.$render = function() {
                return editor.setData(ngModel.$viewValue);
            };
        }
    };
});
```

and i use it as

```
<app-wysiwyg-block label="Description" name="description" ng-model="item.description" error="fieldErrors.description" required="true" cols="12"></app-wysiwyg-block>
```

any number of times in a page and it works just fine in all the modes.