# ckeditor angularjs directive : how to upload multiple images?

Tags: angularjs, ckeditor

I am using ckeditor directive just like :

[Updating textarea value with CKEditor content in Angular JS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18917262/updating-textarea-value-with-ckeditor-content-in-angular-js)

I want to upload multiple images by angularjs directive like this example : 
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/616308/Image-upload-with-CKEditor

How can i do that?

Answer (score 2):

I have use Angular File Upload to do the same thing. I used it as a service not as a directive.

[Angular File Upload](https://github.com/nervgh/angular-file-upload)

[Demo](http://nervgh.github.io/pages/angular-file-upload/examples/simple/)