# CKEditor 4 with AngularJS Have to Click Save Twice

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, ckeditor

I'm using CKEditor 4 with an AngularJS application. When my application loads everything appears to be working correctly as I can see the CKEditor instance. However, when I click the 'save' button and output the data in the CKEditor (writing it to the console) it returns as `undefined`, but when I click save the second time it works as expected. I'm at a loss for what is happening. What am I missing?

I have a pretty simple implementation of this:

**HTML Markup**

```
<textarea id="tbDetails" name="tbDetails" ng-model="event.details" placeholder="Event Details"></textarea>

<button id="btnSave" ng-click="save(event)">Save Event</button>
```

**JavaScript**

```
CKEDITOR.replace('tbDetails');
```

**Save Event Handler (AngularJS)**

```
$scope.save = function () {
    console.log($('#tbDetails').val()); // undefined the 1st time, but works the 2nd time
}
```

Comment: can you provide jsfiddle? or check the below url http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18917262/updating-textarea-value-with-ckeditor-content-in-angular-js

Answer (score 1):

No need to use  `$('#tbDetails').val()`

Try with this

```
$scope.ckeditordata = CKEDITOR.instances.tbDetails.getData();

console.log( CKEDITOR.instances.tbDetails.getData(); )
```

Comment: I have problem with this  On first click of submit ckeditor only gives half characters and than on second submit it gives full data