# CKEditor not showing when AngularJS swap its view

Tags: angularjs, ckeditor

My AngularJS Directive is:

```
.directive('ckEditor', function() {
  return {
    require: '?ngModel',
    link: function(scope, elm, attr, ngModel) {
      var ck = CKEDITOR.replace(elm[0]);

      if (!ngModel) return;
      ck.on('pasteState', function() {
        scope.$apply(function() {
          ngModel.$setViewValue(ck.getData());
        });
      });

      ngModel.$render = function(value) {
        ck.setData(ngModel.$viewValue);
      };
    }
  };
```

Let's say My View is like following:

```
<textarea ck-editor  name="menu_content" style="width:600px; height:300px;" id="menu_content" ng-model="models.menu_content" ub-search-settings=""></textarea>
```

When the view is called CKEditor shows instead of TextArea. It's ok.
Now, my problem is CKEditor not showing when view is call for next time not reloading the whole page.

Answer (score 2):

Add this to your directive:

```
          ck.on('instanceReady', function() {
            ck.setData(ngModel.$viewValue);
          });
```

Comment: Why would you call ck.setData(ngModel.$viewValue) twice?