# ckEditor, AngularJS & Bootstrap 3 Modal - insertText() behaves erratic

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ckeditor, angularjs-directive

I have the following angular directive as per [Updating textarea value with CKEditor content in Angular JS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18917262/updating-textarea-value-with-ckeditor-content-in-angular-js) and [Bind Ckeditor value to model text in angularjs and rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11997246/bind-ckeditor-value-to-model-text-in-angularjs-and-rails)

```
angular.module('ngTeknorix')
 .directive('ckEditor', ['$timeout', function ($timeout) {
  return {
    require: '?ngModel',
    link: function (scope, elm, attr, ngModel) {
        var ck = CKEDITOR.replace(elm[0]);

        if (!ngModel) return;

        ck.on('change', function () {
            scope.$apply(function () {
                ngModel.$setViewValue(ck.getData());
            });
        });

        ngModel.$render = function (value) {
            ck.setData(ngModel.$viewValue);
        };

        // This breaks!!
        scope.addConfirmationLink = function () {
            ck.insertText("Inserted Text");
        }
    }
 };  
}]);
```

This works absolutely fine for normal operations but as soon as i try the insertText or insertHtml functions to insert text at the cursor position it behaves erratic. It sometimes inserts the text once.. and sometimes twice..

Any Ideas?

Note: All this is done inside a Bootstrap modal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Normally ckEditor works absolutely fine with angularJS as a directive.

On 'pastestate' event of the ckeditor you set the value to the angular model :-

```
ck.on('pasteState', function () {
  $timeout(function () {
    ngModel.$setViewValue(ck.getData());
  });
});
```

And the other way round to set the value to the ckEditor you use the $render function.

```
ngModel.$render = function (value) {
  ck.setData(ngModel.$viewValue);
};
```

Everything goes for a toss when you use a ckEditor function like insertText() or insertHtml() as the pastestate event gets fired immediately (otherwise it gets called after a delay). It behaves erratic when the insertText() is called the second time and adds the text twice, thrice the third time and so on.

So to make ckEditor work with Bootstrap Modal and AngularJS we have to use the destroy function of ckeditor on closing the modal....

```
angular.module('ngTeknorix')
.directive('ckEditor', ['$timeout', function ($timeout) {
    return {
        require: '?ngModel',
        link: function ($scope, $element, $attrs, ngModel) {
            $scope.initCkEditor = function () {
                var ck = CKEDITOR.replace($attrs.id);
                ck.on('pasteState', function () {
                    $timeout(function () {
                        ngModel.$setViewValue(ck.getData());
                    });
                });
                ngModel.$render = function () {
                    ck.setData(ngModel.$viewValue);
                };
                $scope.insertText = function (value) {
                    ck.insertText(value);
                }
            };
            $scope.destroyCkEditor = function () {
                if (CKEDITOR.instances[$attrs.id]) {
                    CKEDITOR.instances[$attrs.id].destroy(false);
                }
            };
        }
    };
}]);
```