# How to add custom button to CKEditor when using AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, ckeditor, wysiwyg

With the help of stackoverflow, I am able to use CKEditor with Angularjs.

[The reference I followed](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12021632/1273587)

I have changed the code a bit because I want to use inline mode.

```
var ck = CKEDITOR.inline(elm[0]);
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/cPTr7/626/)

Then, I need to add extra function to CKEditor, so I search and do some experiment on JSFiddle.

[The reference I followed](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25443349/1273587)
The JS Fiddle inside the answer shows that it actually works.

However, when I try to combine the above two, the CKEditor still works, but the custom function is not added.

My code in the directory

```
var ck = CKEDITOR.inline( elm[0] );

if (elm.hasClass('ng-hide')) return;
if (!ngModel) return;

ck.on('pasteState', function() {
    scope.$apply(function() {
        ngModel.$setViewValue(ck.getData());
    });
});

ck.addCommand("mySimpleCommand", {
    exec: function(edt) {
       alert(edt.getData());
    }
});

ck.ui.addButton('SuperButton', {
    label: "Click me",
    command: 'mySimpleCommand',
    toolbar: 'insert',
    icon:'http://chart.apis.google.com/chartchst=d_map_pin_letter&chld=|999999|000000'
});

ngModel.$render = function(value) {
    ck.setData(ngModel.$viewValue);
};
```

[JSFiddle DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/qcy8ncu7/3/)

I really don't know what can be wrong by mixing 2 piece of working code together. What have I missed?